# Trying to create login with react, golang and mysql

Tags: mysql, reactjs, go, axios

this time I am creating a login for a dashboard, the problem is that I cannot identify what is failing, I have the following configuration

**HANDLER CONTROLLER**

```
func Login(username string, pass string) map[string]interface{} {
    db := GetConnection()
    user := &models.User{}
    // sql := "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username'" + user.Username + "'and password ='" + user.Password + "'"

    if db.Where("username = ?", username).First(&user).RecordNotFound() {
        return map[string]interface{}{"message": "Usuario no encontrado"}
    }

    passErr := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(user.Password), []byte(pass))

    if passErr == bcrypt.ErrMismatchedHashAndPassword && passErr != nil {
        return map[string]interface{}{"mesagge": "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos"}
    }

    // buscar cuenta usuario

    accounts := []models.ResponseAccount{}

    db.Table("accounts").Select("id, name").Where("user_id = ?", user.ID).Scan(&accounts)

    // Configuración del response
    responseUser := &models.ResponseUser{
        ID:       user.ID,
        Username: user.Username,
        Accounts: accounts,
    }

    defer db.Close()

    fmt.Println(responseUser)

    //Entrada token

    tokenContent := jwt.MapClaims{
        "user_id": user.ID,
        "expiry":  time.Now().Add(time.Minute ^ 60).Unix(),
    }

    jwtToken := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.GetSigningMethod("HS256"), tokenContent)
    token, err := jwtToken.SignedString([]byte("TokenPassword"))
    HandleErr(err)

    var response = map[string]interface{}{"Message": "Bienvenido"}
    response["jwt"] = token
    response["data"] = responseUser

    return response
}
```

**AXIOS CONFIG**

```
import axios from "axios";

export class AdminService {
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:3001/persona/api/";
    async login() {
        const res = await axios.post(this.baseUrl + "login");
        return res.data;
    }
}
export default new AdminService();
```

**INDEX LOGIN CONFIG**

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    state = {
        form: {
            "username": "",
            "password": ""
        },
        error: false,
        errormsg: ""
    }

    manageChange = async (e) => {
        this.setState({
            form: {
                ...this.state.form,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
            }
        })
        console.log(this.state.form)
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        AdminService.login(this.state.form).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            if (response.data.status === 200) {
                this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
            }
            else {
                this.setState({
                    error: true,
                    errormsg: response.data.message
                })
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <section >
                    <div class="container" >
                        <div class="top"></div>
                        <div class="bottom"></div>
                        <div class="center">
                            <img src={LogoIndex} id='logo-df' />
                            <form >
                                <input placeholder="Usuario" name="username" type="text" onChange={this.manageChange} />
                                <input placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" type="password" onChange={this.manageChange} />
                                <button onClick={this.handleClick} type='submit' className='corner-button' >Entrar</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

I've tried to do other configurations, but I can't go any further, I followed some guides from platforms documentation and I don't understand what it can be

[image]

Comment: Where are you sending the response from the backend to the frontend? According to the error you are sending an empty response from the backend to the frontend